# Javascript/Regexp: Getting facebook album's id from url?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function sa_get_facebook_album_id(url){
    var m = url.match(/\?set=a\.[0-9]*\./);

    return m;
}
```

This function is supposed to return an album's ID after its URL is passed.

But I want to get ONLY the numbers ([0-9]) and nothing else.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use a **capturing group** to store the `id`:

```
function sa_get_facebook_album_id(url){
    var m = url.match(/\?set=a\.([0-9]*)\./);
    return m[1];
}
```

The capturing group is in parenthesis, i.e., `([0-9]*)`, and you can refer to it later, using `m[1]`. Note that `m[0]` contains the entire matched string, `m[1]` the *first* captured group, and so on.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RQCm4/)**.